# Error occurred in partition processor while running 2 instances of java sdk app to listen event hub

Tags: java, azure-eventhub

dependencies getting used

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob
            </artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have a eventhub with 4 partition.
I am producing messages continuously on the eventhub.
and listening with EventProcessorClient.

Initially 1 instance is up and listening all the 4 partitions.
In between i am starting the 2nd instance with same consumer group on the same machine. My expectation was partition will automatically get re balances and partition ownership will get distributed to 2 listeners (having same consumer group).

But i am facing 2 issues

1. both instances are listening same messages of the same partition (contrast to 1 parition 1 consumer ownership).
2. getting below error and similar error continously.

Error occurred in partition processor for partition 3, com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: New receiver 'nil' with higher epoch of '0' is created hence current receiver 'nil' with epoch '0' is getting disconnected. If you are recreating the receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used. TrackingId:70cb6fce00000f030023f5515f0f1e63_G27_B21, SystemTracker:......:test~32766|$default, Timestamp:2020-07-15T15:19:19, errorContext[NAMESPACE: ......, PATH: test/ConsumerGroups/$default/Partitions/3, REFERENCE_ID: ......, LINK_CREDIT: 499].

Can some one help me out in the understanding and results of the issues.

Comment: 1. Both instances will not be allowed to process the same partition. If one instance takes ownership of a partition, ownership will be revoked from the other instance by the service. There is a very small window of overlap before the service disconnects the link from one instance.
2. This error occurs when the service disconnects a partition as another instance took ownership of that partition.

It should eventually settle down to a stable ownership configuration with each instance owning 2 partitions. If this doesn't happen, including more logs in your post might help in answering this.

Comment: @srikanta 1) Are u saying during the ownership transfer period message can be read by 2 or more instances?  2) the error occuring are not to worry about if they are  for a small time?

Comment: With respect to #1 - the partition cannot actively be read by more than a single processor; the service enforces this constraint.  However, when ownership of a partition is changed, the old processor may already have a set of events in memory that is being dispatched for processing and for which a checkpoint was not yet created.  The new processor would read some (or all) of those same events.   While there is only one active reader for the partition, the net effect is that two processors are acting on some of the same events.  This is why it is important that your processing be idempotent.

Comment: @JesseSquire thanks , that clarifies